# Reset furnace (heater) often to get my fan to work.

Tags: fans, heater

Why do I have to reset my furnace (heater) often to get my fan to work? The thermostat works properly but the fan some time is not turned on. Reset the furnace and/or the limit control switch works for a while but the problem will come back.

Comment: What is the make and model of the unit? Does the heater work but not the fan, or does the whole unit not work?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Exchange. Model numbers? A picture of the limit switch? An explanation of what it means to "reset the furnace"? (Any or all would help.)

Comment: The model is Day & Night 350A. Reset the furnace means power down & then power back up. Everything works, the flame was ignited, the furnace hums but the fan is not turned on.

Comment: Have you turned the furnace off and jiggled the connections to heat sensors and blower motor yet? These can build up insulating oxides over time, and a good jiggle is sometimes all it takes to get everything working again.

Comment: I had to replace the capacitor to the fan, $120 part & labor.

Comment: Those staring capacitors *do* go bad. Next time you'll have something to check before calling the repairman. Caps are a lot cheaper than repairmen.

Answer (score 1):

You might need a new control board in the furnace or just a relay replacement. Anything more than a once a year reset means there's a failure somewhere.

Comment: This is a very generic answer, bordering on uselessness.  Sometimes it's more useful to request more information, than trying to be the first to answer.

Comment: Sorry to offend. But, a reset should rarely if ever be needed during normal operation. Maybe, I should just forget my personal experience & waste everyone's time with idiotic nonsense. You know, like clueless morons saying a circuit interrupter isn't a circuit breaker & overcurrent is the same thing as an overload. Thanks but no thanks for your advice.

Comment: There's no need to be nasty. I'm trying to give you some advice, to help you provide useful help to folks that need it. While it's true that a furnace should not have to be reset. Saying 'maybe replace the control board or a relay', is not an extremely useful answer.

Comment: I appreciate that, but I thought I was quite clear in implying that they should get their HVAC guy or firm out to address the problem & quit the habit of resetting...in other & more precise words.

Comment: The only thing you implied, was that the OP should replace the control board and maybe a relay.

Comment: Get real. They're pushing the reset button! They don't have any understanding of the system, they're just doing what works until the system finally notices the fault wasn't fixed.

Comment: And they're here asking for help. Possibly because they can't afford to call a technician, randomly replace parts, or replace the whole unit. If you're not here to help, why answer at all?

Comment: Because, they probably asked a year ago "why isn't my furnace blowing" & someone here, irresponsibly & quite incompletely, said "just push the reset button". Now, they're back hoping for another easy "fix" that's suddenly now permanent. Sense finally dawns on them or they end up with no heat at all or too much heat when the furnace catches fire.

Comment: You certainly have a low opinion of the community here.

Comment: Nope the community does a fantastic job, but the OP 's will take the easiest answer & run as far as they can with it...just like real people.